# How do vectors change under branching rules for $SU(8) \rightarrow USp(8)$

Tags: representation-theory, branching-rules

The branching rules for $SU(8) \rightarrow USp(8)$ are:
\begin{align}
&8\rightarrow 8 \\
&28\rightarrow 1+27\\
&56\rightarrow 8+48\\
&70\rightarrow 1+27+42
\end{align}
My question is about how vectors in the representation of $SU(8)$ change into vectors in the representation of $USp(8)$.

To be specific, for example, assume a 28-dimensional vector $F^{AB}$ with $A,B=1,...,8$, antisymmetric with $AB$, transforms in the representation **28** of $SU(8)$. Now since we know the branching rule $28\rightarrow 1+27$, in the $USp(8)$, the 28-dimensional vector $F^{AB}$ will become a 1-dimensional vector that is invariant under $USp(8)$ and a 27-dimensional vector that is in the representation **27** of $USp(8)$.

I know the 1-dimensional vector can be constructed by $F^{AB}\Omega_{AB}$, where $\Omega_{AB}$ is the symplectic invariant matrix. However, I do NOT know how to construct the 27-dimensional vector using the components of $F^{AB}$. Anyone know how to do it?

I also need to know how to deal with representation **56** and **70**.

Thank you so much!